# is it possible to pass interface or base class type to java.lang.Class as generic type

Tags: java

I have an interface A and classes B,C which extends A.

I want to store class types of B and C in one ArrayList.
In order to do that I have create a list and add elements like below;

```
private List<Class<A>> classes = new ArrayList<>();

classes.add(B.class);
classes.add(C.class);
```

it doesn't accept to add these types.
is there any way to do it?

Comment: `Class<? extends A>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Benjamin said, the below is valid and compiles. If it doesn't work for you then there must be something significant that you're omitting:

```
public class Main {
    interface A {}
    class B implements A {}
    class C implements A {}
    private List<Class<? extends A>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
    {
        classes.add(B.class);
        classes.add(C.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that the above is [valid for classes](https://tio.run/##ZU/LDoIwELz7FXsEE/sDIAa46smj8bDShhShkLaghvDttdLGF3ubnck8KhxwU9GrMbzpWqmhsg/Sa16TdbTq@kvNCyhqVAoOyAWMK7DnHimM0xfMgN01E3RB5Euik3xAzUBp1DZgz5WO85c43n3ESeIMmIItCHaDVEp8zNokCKPZyBu4Wu9IpghSGmRkRl76z@Y/rO/lBnvXoeUUGjs7OGrJRXk6A8pShXbEZMwT) as well as interfaces